# The complement of any set of first category on the line is dense iff the intersection of any sequence of dense open sets is dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dense-subspaces

I want to prove that
The complement of any set of first category on the line is dense iff the intersection  of any sequence of dense open sets is dense.
but I don't need to prove this in general. I need to prove that in R and I want to prove this using the following definitions:
A set A is dense in the interval I if A has a nonempty intersection with every subinterval of I.
It is called dense if it is dense in the line R.
A set A is nowhere dense if it is dense in no interval, that is, if every interval has a subinterval contained in the complement of A.

I have proved that if the complement of any set of first category on the line is dense then the intersection  of any sequence of dense open sets is dense.

on the other side: I tried to prove that like this:

suppose that the intersection  of any sequence of dense open sets is dense. let A is a set of first category. we have to prove that $A^c $ is dense.
since A is a set of first category then where $ \{A_n\}_{n\in N} $ is a sequence of no where dense sets
$ A= \bigcup_{n \in N} A_n$
then $ A^c = \bigcap_{n \in N} A_n^c $

since $ A_n $ is no where dense then $ A_n^c $ is dense.

if I prove that $ A_n^c $ is open then the prove is done. but I can't see that.

Comment: You may want to consider using single dollar signs to enclose most of this math without making a new line each time.  It really makes no sense in the middle of a sentence to cut it off for a single union or intersection on its own line.

Comment: @MW I didn't know how to write like that. I just learned from your comment. Thank you. I edited

Comment: Both conditions characterize Baire spaces in general, and yes, they are equivalent for arbitrary topological spaces. Perhaps you wanted to prove this ? Or did you want to prove that $\mathbb R$ is a Baire space (which is also true)?
But it doesn't make sense to prove their *equivalence* for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ulli I want to prove this in R. I want to prove this using the definitions above. I konw there is an another definition for nowhere sets but I need to prove this using these definitions.